# Load CSS from PHP like loading IMG

Tags: php, html, css

i can use the following code to load IMG file:

```
<img src="http://www.www.com/image-name.php"/>
```

now, i was wondering how i could load CSS from an external php?

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://www.www.com/main-css-file.php' />
```

the reason is because the css will be in theme folder with a htaccess file with full deny.

any help appreciated!

Comment: Err. Like that. Why would it be otherwise?

Comment: i mean load from http://www.www.com/main-css-file.php - am i missing a header type? - the reason is because the css will be in theme folder with a htaccess file with full deny.

Comment: The same way as the image. (Except you set the content type to say "This is CSS" instead of "This is JPEG")

Answer (score 0):

Very easy.

```
<?php header('Content-type: application/pdf'); ?>

h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
}

p {
    font-size: 14p
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Content-Type` header to `text/css` before returning data:

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/css; charset=utf-8');
  $color = '#d0e4fe';
?>

body {
    background-color: <?php echo $color ?>;
}
```